# haskell compile program nothing show

Tags: haskell

```
module Arith where

data Term = 
    TmTrue
  | TmFalse
  | If Term Term Term
  | Zero
  | Succ Term
  | Pred Term
  | IsZero Term
  deriving (Show,Eq)

isnumericval :: Term -> Bool
isnumericval Zero    = True
isnumericval (Succ t1) = isnumericval t1
isnumericval t = False

isval TmTrue  = True
isval TmFalse = True
isval t = isnumericval t

eval1 (If TmTrue  t2 t3) = t2
eval1 (If TmFalse t2 t3) = t3
eval1 (If t1 t2 t3) = 
      let t1' = eval1 t1 
      in If t1' t2  t3 
eval1 (Succ t1) =
      let t1' = eval1 t1 
      in Succ t1' 
eval1 (Pred Zero) = Zero
eval1 (Pred (Succ nv1)) | isnumericval nv1 = nv1
eval1 (Pred t1) =
      let t1' = eval1 t1 
      in Pred t1' 
eval1 (IsZero Zero) = TmTrue
eval1 (IsZero (Succ nv1)) | isnumericval nv1 = TmFalse 
eval1 (IsZero t1) = 
      let t1' = eval1 t1 
      in IsZero t1' 
eval1 t = t -- otherwise, no need to evaluate

eval t =
  let t' = eval1 t
  in if t' == t then t else eval t 


tes1 = print( eval (Succ (Pred Zero)))
```

i would like to ask about this code, how can i compile this program in haskell? i try to load module such with ghci but nothing show. i want to call and evaluate tes1 , but how can i call it?

Comment: I have not checked whether this is actually called in your code (please reduce its size if you want me to do that), but it certainly seems to have the potential for an infinite loop: if the `t' == t` conditional in `eval t` fails (I haven't checked whether it can), then you have an infinite loop as `eval` is again evaluated with the same argument as before.

Comment: @gspr how can i reduce the size?

Comment: If you load this and type `tes1` in GHCi, what happens? (It looks like you need `else eval t'` in the definition of `eval` at the very end to avoid infinite recursion)

Comment: @kill: Use your understanding of the code to remove pieces until you can reproduce the core of the problem. This may or may not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a step-by-step guide how to deal with such a situation.

1. Creating file `Arith.hs`, with the code you gave
2. `$ ghci Arith.hs` on the shell.

   ```
   [1 of 1] Compiling Arith            ( Arith.hs, interpreted )
   Ok, one module loaded.
   *Arith>
   ```
3. `*Arith> tes1`
4. Nothing seems to happen here, the prompt is frozen. This happens somewhat often in Haskell, since the recursion style can easily be done to get an infinite loop (and unlike in Agda or Coq, there's no totality checker). You can get out of this by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

   ```
   *Arith> tes1
   ^CInterrupted.
   ```
5. So where's the problem? There are a couple of ways to find this out. In this case, I would just toy around in GHCi a bit, in particular see if already `eval1` has the same behaviour:

   ```
   *Arith> eval1 $ Succ (Pred Zero)
   Succ Zero
   ```

   Ok, so that seems to be ok. Also if I call it multiple times (as `eval` might do in proper operation)?

   ```
   *Arith> take 6 . iterate eval1 $ Succ (Pred Zero)
   [Succ (Pred Zero),Succ Zero,Succ Zero,Succ Zero,Succ Zero,Succ Zero]
   ```

   Looks pretty good and indeed converges against the fixpoint that `eval` is supposed to find.
6. So that means the problem is in `eval`. Fortunately that is a really small function, so just go through its evaluation manually in your head.

   ```
   eval $ Succ (Pred Zero)
    ≡ let t' = eval1 $ Succ (Pred Zero)
             ≡ Succ Zero
      in if t' == Succ (Pred Zero)
          then Succ (Pred Zero)
          else eval $ Succ (Pred Zero)
   ```

   Ok, the `t' == Succ (Pred Zero)` condition is not fulfilled, so we go into the `else` branch, where... oops, we've seen `eval $ Succ (Pred Zero)` before, right? It's what we *started* with! So that bit is wrong. What you actually want is recurse on the *reduced* form, i.e.

   ```
   eval t =
      let t' = eval1 t
      in if t' == t then t else eval t'
   ```